# The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'. The '!' will have no effect because the receiver can't be null

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that for this error I need to add a '!' before the '.' because of Dart null safety. But upon adding the null check, I get the following error:
***The '!' will have no effect because the receiver can't be null. Try removing the '!'***

How do I fix this?
I am making the sign-in and register page of my app and have added a button to switch between the pages. This button works on the concept of bool and reversing it. And then it switches pages depending on the value. Here's the code:

### Sign In Page

```
import 'package:brew_crew/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function? toggleView;

  SignIn({this.toggleView});

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  //textfield state
  String? email;
  String? password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade100,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade400,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text('Sign in to Brew Crew'),
        // Button to switch pages starts here:
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                widget!.toggleView();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: Text('Register')),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 50),
          child: Form(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      email = val;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      password = val;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    print(email);
                    print(password);
                  },
                  child: Text('Sign in'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

### Register Page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'sign_in.dart';
import 'package:brew_crew/screens/authenticate/authenticate.dart';
import 'package:brew_crew/services/auth.dart';

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function? toggleView;

  Register({this.toggleView});

  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  String? email;
  String? password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade100,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade400,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text('Sign up to Brew Crew'),
        // Button to switch page
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                widget.toggleView();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: Text('Sign In')),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 50),
          child: Form(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      email = val;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      password = val;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    print(email);
                    print(password);
                  },
                  child: Text('Sign up'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

### The Logic Behind The Button

```
import 'package:brew_crew/screens/authenticate/register.dart';
import 'package:brew_crew/screens/authenticate/sign_in.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Authenticate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticateState createState() => _AuthenticateState();
}

class _AuthenticateState extends State<Authenticate> {
  bool showSignIn = true;

  void toggleView() {
    setState(() {
      showSignIn = !showSignIn;
      print(showSignIn);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (showSignIn == true) {
      return SignIn(toggleView: toggleView);
    } else {
      return Register(toggleView: toggleView);
    }
  }
}
```

I know it's a long question. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask where will you place the `!`

Comment: I placed it at ```widget!.toggleview();```

Comment: required is already there in the constructor. not working...The if check is also not working

Comment: toggleView can be null or not?

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways I suggest. You can use any **one** of them

1.You can change it like

```
if(widget.toggleView != null){
    widget.toggleView();
}
```

2.add `require` in constructor to make `toggleView` cannot be `null`

```
Register({require this.toggleView});
```

3.if you don't want to change code and guarantee `toggleView` will never be `null`. Try this

```
onPressed: widget.toggleView!
```

One more thing change is

```
///final Function? toggleView; should not be accepted for onPressed
///you can use VoidCallback or Function()
final VoidCallback? toggleView;
/// final Function()? toggleView;
```

Use `VoidCallback` **or** `Function()` instead of `Function` for the `onPressed`, and it should work

Comment: The 3rd solution did remove the errors, but the button still didn't function. I think I'll have to do it with routes now.

Comment: @NamanBansal I update my answer for solving button not work, would you mind to try it again

Comment: Hi Sam, it still didn't work so I am using routes now. It's working with routes. thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add exclamation mark after toggleView and before parentheses when you call the function in the action of the flat button in both register page and sign in page like so :

onPress: () {

widget.toggleView!();

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).